# Confidence intervals, Coefficient of variance & box plots

Tags: statistics

here's the background:

I've stochastically modelled 3 techniques of culling a badger population over a ten year period. It quite nicely gives me the mean expected final population at the end of the 10-year period but I'd like to meaningfully show the spread of data (preferably in a graphical way).

Being hopeless at maths I'm in a muddle over how to show the spread, particularly as the confidence interval around the mean, the coefficient of variance and the box plot of the data don't necessarily agree to the data spread!

Could someone be kind enough to explain the difference/real purpose of these 3 methods (or any others I should know about) so I may select the most appropriate one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We call confidence interval if one is not interested in estimating the parameters or testing some hypothesis rather he wishes to establish a lower or upper bound or both.

Whenever we want to compare the variablity of the two data sets which differs widely in their averages or which are measured in different units, we do not simply calculate the absolute measures of dispersion but we calculate the relative measures of dispersion which are pure numbers independent of the units of measurement. Here we call Coefficient of variance.

Lastly Box plot is a graphical display that simultaneously displays several important features of the data such as location or central tendency, spread or dispersion etc.

So, I think in your case Box plot will be a good representative of spread of your data. Since you prefer a graphical way Box plot is better than others.

That's  all from me.

Comment: Thank-you for explaining it simply!